# Scala <member> is not a member of <class>

Tags: scala

I have a set of scala class which I'm trying to utilize:

`FileA.scala`

```scala
abstract class ResourceType[T](val amount: T) {
}

class Cpu(amount: Double) extends ResourceType[Double](amount){
}

class Memory(amount: ByteSize) extends ResourceType[ByteSize](amount){
}


class Storage(amount: ByteSize) extends ResourceType[ByteSize](amount){
}

class RuntimeResources(cpus: Double = 1, memSize: ByteSize = 0.B, storageSize: ByteSize = 0.B) {
  val cpu: Cpu = new Cpu(cpus)
  val mem: Memory = new Memory(memSize)
  val storage: Storage = new Storage(storageSize)
}
```

Then somewhere else in the codebase (different file, same package), `FileB.scala`

```scala
...
val x: Seq[RuntimeResources] = ...
...
x.map(_.mem.amount.toMB)
```

However, when I try to compile this I get

```
value amount is not a member of <package>.Memory
```

I think I am misunderstanding the access modifiers of the classes. I don't really understand why this doesn't compile. When I move the classes from `FileA.scala` into `FileB.scala` it seems to compile fine, however I can't move the code into that file for other reasons. Why does simply moving the code to from `FileA.scala` to `FileB.scala` allow it to compile, and is there any way around this?

Comment: What exactly is `resources` in the map function?

Comment: Oh, good point. I realized I made a mistake on the type of `x` when converting the code. It should just be `_.mem.amount.toMB`. I've updated the question.

Comment: Can you please create a github repo reproducing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason why this would not compile.

I am working with a large codebase (100k+ LoC), and in another file in the same package there was a `sealed trait Memory` which clashed with the `Memory` class in the function above.

When I renamed one of the classes, it compiled fine. I am surprised the compiler does not flag that as an issue. It seemed that the trait took precedence in the compiler.

Edit: After discussion in the comments, I've filed a bug against scala for this issue: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12289

Comment: _"I am surprised the compiler does not flag that as an issue"_ flag what as an issue?

Comment: The clash of a trait and a class having the same name within the same package - in my case it was `Memory`. The compiler didn't give any notion that there was another entity with the same name within the package.

Comment: Are you sure it was in the same package? I am pretty sure the compiler does not only warn but actually errors in that case. However, if you have them in different packages and imported in the same place then yes the second import will override the first one that is basic management of namespace.

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure everything is in the same package. It did not warn or error about the name clash. Though one thing I did just realize is that the files actually exist in different sbt modules. So the first module, say A, compiles fine, but the name clash occurs in another SBT module, say B. The same package name is used in module A and B

Comment: Sorry I edited my previous comment -- see above. I noticed the scala package is actually split across separate SBT modules. The first module compiles fine, the 2nd module defines a dependency on the first and within the package declares the clashing name

Comment: You are right, I just tested it. That sounds like a bug; would you like to [report it](https://github.com/scala/bug)?

Comment: I've filed this bug: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12289